# Command binding in nested data template + wpf + mvvm

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I need to pass values from view to view model still preserving mvvm. Let me explain the issue.

```
<UserControl x:Class="SelectorView" ...>
<ListView Name="gridListView" ItemsSource="{Binding... }">
        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="false"/>
            </Style>
        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Border>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                    <Label x:Name="vLabel" Content="{Binding VCValue}"/>
                    <ListView Name="checkBoxListView" ItemsSource="{Binding CList}">
                        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <CheckBox Command="{Binding DataContext.OnCheckedCommand,RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}}" Margin="5" Click="CheckBox_Click" IsChecked="{Binding SelectedValue, Mode=TwoWay}"  Content="{Binding Current, Mode=OneWay }"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListView>
                </StackPanel>
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
   </UserControl>
```

In above code, When user checks/unchecks the checkbox, i need to send value(content) of checkbox and also value of vLabel from view to view model. Both are within nested Data template. Earlier I used visualtreehelper to retrieve the same but I need to do this more in mvvm format. Hence, want to know if its doable using Command binding and how ? In check box, i binded to OnCheckedCommand but that doesn't seem to invoke OnCheckedExecuted() on check/uncheck. 
So, how do i get the content of checkbox and vLabel on check/uncheck?

```
public class MainViewModel
{
    public DelegateCommand<object> OnCheckedCommand { get; private set; }

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        OnCheckedCommand = new DelegateCommand<object>(OnCheckedExecuted, CanCheck);
    }
    private void OnCheckedExecuted(object parameter)
    {

    }

    private bool CanCheck(object parameter)
    {
        return true;
    }

}
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: It sounds like what you want is simply to use  `TwoWay` binding mode. Unless there's some business logic execution associated with checking/unchecking your checkbox, using a command for that purpose is probably just an overkill.

Comment: @jsanalytics: Thanks for your reply.  I do have TwoWay binding set at CheckBox(in above xaml). As I mentioned i need to retrieve the value of checkbox & also vLabel and use these values to be populated in another UI on check/uncheck. So, can you please explain more in detail what you were trying to say about TwoWay binding that will help me achieve them?

Comment: @jsanalytics: Ok, I see what you say...I changed the mode in Content="{Binding Current, Mode=OneWay} to TwoWay and still doesn't seem to work. IS there any other way in mvvm form that I can do to get those values?

Comment: Your `Current` property is not triggering `PropertyChanged` event. Always check VS **Output** window for binding errors. Follow at least one simple tutorial on how to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` properly. You're making basic mistakes in your implementation.